# Cardview isn't taking its full width ( gets cropped by 2% from left )

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-cardview

I have a cardview with a the following layout :

```
- Main Relative Layout
-- Header Container ( Linear )
-- Body Container ( Linear )
-- Footer Container ( Linear )
```

The cardview gets cropped from the left by 2%, it's not the full width, you can tell by comparing the border ( radius ) and the difference between the card and the end .

Screenshot : [HERE](http://i.imgur.com/IxuUlc0.jpg) .

My layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/lift_on_touch">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:text="Test League"
                android:id="@+id/league"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#32000000"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/match_container"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/first_team_container">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/first_team_icon"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="First Team"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:id="@+id/first_team_title"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/first_team_icon" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first_team_container"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/first_team_container"
                android:id="@+id/match_result">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:id="@+id/first_result"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="-"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/dash"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:id="@+id/second_result"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/match_result"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/match_result"
                android:id="@+id/second_team_container">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/second_team_icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Second Team"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:id="@+id/second_team_title"

                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/second_team_icon" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/info_container"
            android:layout_below="@+id/match_container"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Status"            android:textSize="12sp"

                android:id="@+id/status" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date"
                android:id="@+id/date" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"

                android:text="Time"
                android:id="@+id/time" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is your realativelayout inside another layout?

Comment: what do you want to achieve here?

Comment: @Veeresh Charantimath a margin, adding 10dp margin to the parent RelativeLayout didn't do anything, adding it to the cardview did, when it's in the parent, there's no margin at all.

Comment: How do you actually want it to be?

Comment: with full margin by 5 dp, without that bug .

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. It would be great if you have a screenshot of what you want

Comment: I want to add Margin, but without having a problem - what is the problem here?

Comment: Check the screenshot, there is no rounded corners on the left, because when i'm adding margin, it's getting cropped, and this is the problem. It should NOT get cropped, and should add a margin without any visual bug in the cardview.

Comment: Add android:padding="10dp" to parent relativelayout of cardview and check if thats what you want

Comment: I swear i tried that a lot of times, i'm not that noob, but it worked this time, maybe because i removed some card_view attrs, post it as an answer please .

Comment: I have updated my existing answer

Comment: It says after 13 hours, will be added in that time, thanks for your help!.

Comment: Use android:contentInsetLeft="0dp" and app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your **CardView** remove this line `android:layout_margin="10dp"`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/lift_on_touch">
```

Update:

Add `android:padding="10dp"` to parent relativelayout of cardview.

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath it does not have this android:layout_margin="10dp"

Comment: What do you mean by that? The cardview in the question has android:layout_margin="10dp" but my answer does not have that

Comment: Sorry my bad! Did not notice that you meant Remove

Comment: I have seen image posted in question, its cardview is cutting from left... margin is there..

Comment: Here's the thing, when i remove this, Cardview's shadow disappear, and the margin disappear, I've added the margin to the parent RelativeLayout, still the same thing.